# 1:N Relationship Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I working on a form and i'm kind of stumped as to how i should go about implementing the add a new address functionality. Ideally the add a new address should create new inputs for the address on the same page and the save button would save (either add or update) all of the information on the page.

Here's a mockup of what the form will look like:

[image]

Right now this Form exists in a strongly typed view which has a ViewModel that looks like this:

```
public class PersonInputViewModel
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}
    public string MiddleName {get;set}

    public AddressModel PrimaryAddress {get;set;}
    public AddressModel SecondaryAddress {get;set;}
}
```

Now with this view model i don't really know how i should go about handling a new addition of an address since right now this view model only allows two address. If i got rid of the PrimaryAddress and SecondaryAddress and opted for a List of AddressModels how would i go about creating the inputs for addresses on the view?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: i've edited it a bit in hopes that my question is clarified a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) useful. It's even more general solution as it applies to a list of entities (not only a primary and secondary addresses) but the concept could be the same. You would define a partial view which will contain the necessary fields for editing an address and when the user decides to add the secondary address use AJAX to inject the additional fields into the existing form.